# How to implement the cost sensitive classifier in weka?

Tags: java, weka, classification

Can anyone give me a simple example of how to use the cost sensitive classifier in my java code with weka?

I don't quite understand the way of defining the base classifier and the cost matrix. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[MetaCost][1]`:

```
Classifier myClassifier = ...
CostMatrix myCostMatrix = ...
Instances myData = ...

MetaCost metaCost = new MetaCost();
metaCost.setClassifier(myClassifier);
metaCost.setCostMatrix(myCostMatrix);
metaCost.buildClassifier(myData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've got couple doubts: 

(1) Shouldn't I use the `weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier`? 

(2) Should the `myClassifier` trained before performing the `metaCost.setClassifier(myClassifier);` in your example? 

(3)Would you pls give me an example of defining a 2X2 `myCostMatrix`?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: 1) With `MetaCost` you can use any classifier that you want. 2)No 3) http://weka.wikispaces.com/CostMatrix

Comment: In Weka 3.7.4 there doesn't seem to be a MetaCost. However, you can replace MetaCost with `CostSensitiveClassifier`

Comment: @Max -- As of today, [MetaCost is released as an independent jar library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/metaCost)